# How to pass in a dynamic route with Director.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

So I am trying to create a router that allows me to pass data through the URL to a dynamic function.

I can get a function to fire a route that works like this -

```
const router = new Router({
        "/intro": () => {
          store.showIntro()
        }
```

But how do I make it fire a route dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple with Director. Use the `:param` syntax:

```
    const router = new Router({
       "/intro": () => {
         store.showIntro()
       },
       "/api/:stringParam": (stringParam) => store.doSomething(stringParam),
    }).configure({ ... }).init()
```

The `stringParam` can then be passed in dynamically, eg

```
www.website.com/api/thing
```

Here is a link to the Director docs:
https://github.com/flatiron/director#url-parameters